Use and save plots created by scikit learn RocCurveDisplay with matplotlib's functions
I have created a plot with scikit's RocCurveDisplay class and I cannot figure out how to save this plot. I cannot find a way to use matplotlib's functions like savefig() somehow. I would also like to use the plots of RocCurveDisplay in matplotlib's subplots(). Is this possible? Could someone help, and if possible elaborate a little?

The RocCurveDisplay's plot uses a set of subplots (1x1) if no axes is provided.
If you need more than one, you can simply build your own and pass each ax to the plot :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(7, 5))

# used inputs from the docs (Visualizations with Display Objects)

roc_display.plot(ax=ax1) # RocCurveDisplay's plot
pr_display.plot(ax=ax2) # the other plots (eventually)

# to save an image for example
plt.savefig("display_object_skl.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")

plt.show()

